Is the E-710 refinement explained in the game lore?
Recently (Apr 2024) the community just completed a major order related to killing Terminids, and the order success message mentioned 'E-710 Refinement'. I have highlighted the section in green.

Is this material ever explained in the game lore, or what Super Earth is doing with it? What is "Terminid biomass production"?

I think its kind of "danced around" in the game, maybe enough for an answer, but not sure.  For example, the one person on your ship will mention something about "alien farms" used to collect the E-710 - thats probably the "Terminid Biomass production".  There is kind of a joke going around that "710" upside down and backwards is "oil", which could be a gimmick towards jokes around "oil" and mainly the U.S (or democratic countries)? (just google "Oil Memes").

All that together is probably why those anti-Super Earth propaganda transmissions you sometimes optionally destroy on missions say something like "the aliens are a Super Earth Construct" - as talked about here https://www.reddit.com/r/Helldivers/comments/1ay8akw/terminids_are_a_false_flag_op/
